# Getting reddit bot to generate a random reply to submission

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I'm working on a bot using PRAW to generate a link from a text file. Here's my code:

```
import praw
from random import choice
import re

reddit = praw.Reddit(user_agent='XXX',
                  client_id='XXX',
                  client_secret='XXX',
                  username='XXX',
                  password='XXX')

with open("links.txt") as f:
    lines = [l.rstrip() for l in f]

subreddit = reddit.subreddit('SUBREDDIT')

for submission in subreddit.stream.submissions:
    if re.search("!TRIGGER WORD", submission.title, re.IGNORECASE):
        submission.reply(choice(lines))
```

After running my script, I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 16, in <module>
    for submission in subreddit.stream.submissions:
TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable
```

Any ideas?

Edit: I forgot my parentheses after this line:

```
for submission in subreddit.stream.submissions:
```

It should look like this:

```
for submission in subreddit.stream.submissions():
```

or this:

```
for submission in subreddit.stream.submissions(skip_existing=True):
```

The latter will only look for new submissions after the stream was started. If you want to reply with a random choice, but not using a file, you could do this:

- import your libraries:

  ```
  import praw

  import random
  ```

Create reddit instance:

```
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id="my client id",
                     client_secret="my client secret",
                     user_agent="my user agent",
                     username="my username",
                     password="my password")
```

- Create a list like this:

  ```
  choices = ['choice', 'choice2', 'choice3']
  ```
- Then check if your trigger is in the title and reply with random choice:

  ```
  for submission in subreddit.stream.submissions():
     if "trigger" in submission.title:
       submission.reply(random.choice(choices))
  ```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted is different than the code in your traceback. The code you posted should work; while the code in your traceback indicates you forgot to call `submissions`. That line should be

```
for submission in subreddit.stream.submissions():
```

or

```
for submission in subreddit.stream.submissions(skip_existing=True):
```

but not

```
for submission in subreddit.stream.submissions:
```